# anjlab-bootstrap, uninitialized constant Bootstrap::Rails::Application, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

Included `@import "twitter/bootstrap";` in `application.css.scss`

Included `//= require twitter/bootstrap` in `application.js`

My GEMFILE:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0' 
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails',:github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails', :branch => '3.0.0'
```

Comment: Did you `bundle install` or `gem install anjlab-bootstrap-rails`?

Comment: bundle install after adding line: gem'anjlab-bootstrap-rails'...

Comment: Did it error out?  Your `Gemfile` looks like there's an extra space in the `:github` value...

Comment: Gem was installed successfully. This extra space is mystake while copying here. I got uninitialized error when starting server.